# Sign In vs Log In

Tags: authentication

Using Web apps, I started to believe that these are synonyms. But, suddenly, at the bottom, developing a web app, I received the following response from a Google server:

```
{"google_logged_in":false,"signed_in":true,"method":"AUTO"}
```

They definitely differentiate between signing in and logging it. Google is dealing with security and definitely has a strong security team to understand all the fine differences. But, I do not know how to ask them.

I know that `Sign In for free` is much more attractive than `Log In for free`. This suggests that signing in is more difficult to get but does not explain the meaning of these things. Why signing in is more forbidden?

**What is asked**. I do not know why people decided that this is question about google terminology. No, I give the google as an example. Which associations do you associate when you hear Sign In and what is different when you hear Log In? I see that people in security field do differentiate the terms, at least sometimes. My example demonstrates this. Thank you for explaining the sense, intended by Google. It was really new for me. But, I want to hear if these rules are universal, which sense do security people intend when talk about this this matter and use these terms?

My fault is that I assume that people on the Earth understand that universal rules are the strongest ones. So, if you can give a general answer, you should prefer it. It would be appropriate through to explain what google intends and probably come up with some more examples if you can, exposing how they fall into general conception, because the difference seems very thin and difficult to notice.

Comment: Would you care to share with us what script you're using?  I think I understand the difference implied but would like to validate it first.

Comment: @JuliePelletier It is [`gapi.auth.authorize((clientId, scope, handleAuthResult)` produces `log('auth result = ' + JSON.stringify(authResult.status))`](https://jsfiddle.net/qjhoLfd9/8). But, probably I better delete my question because people obviously do not want to see the damned questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has "sign in tokens" to be used across apps and websites.

*"google_logged_in":false,"signed_in":true*

That just means the user did not log in to his Google account, the user is signed in to the app or website directly.

Note: if a user is logged in to his Google account, certain websites such as youtube allows automatic sign in via the Google account credentials. I believe this is what you are asking, the difference between log in and sign in (specific to this case).

**Updated due to comments below:**

@LittleAlien I am not entirely sure if it helps you. I did work in the security for more than a few years now though I cannot claim to speak for everyone working in security. This is my two cents.

they are just code variable names. I can imagine it being the case of google_signed_in; logged_in and it still perfectly serves the purpose. For the sake of discussion, if there were to be another means to authenticate, for instance via facebook, it could either be facebook_logged_in or facebook_signed_in, it really does not matter.

Try googling "log in vs sign in", most people seem to agree there is no difference.

I have a feeling you may be thinking that sign in is more secure/complicated than log in. But I stick by my understanding that both are the same no matter what is the underlying authentication or verification processes you can use log in and sign in interchangeably, unless one intentionally, purposefully chooses to differentiate one over the other. That would be a specific case and not be the general norm.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40893/discussion-on-answer-by-john-sign-in-vs-log-in).